What could be potential reasons for Android to not copy .obb to Android/obb during deployment through USB?
I'm deploying a mobile game through the Unreal Engine platform (Quick Launch) to my Xiaomi through a USB cable. When it's installed, the game runs automatically but it's immediately closed.
After a bit of research, I found out that there are no .obb files inside the Android/obb folder for this game. If I place the .obb manually into this folder, the game begins to work as expected.
What could be the reason that the .obb is not copied during deployment?
Actually, it was working well until recently. I cannot imagine what happened...

Are you sure this was working before on does not work without any change to the system? May be the obb file swas simply still present when you installed the APK file. Because all installation hints about adb and obb I found mention that you have to install the obb file, manually.

yes, I am sure, it was working before. Which type of change in system do you mean? Where could check if adb and obb were present? Could you elaborate please?

The "system" is Android. Most devices receive every 1-3 months a system update and once in a year a major version upgrade. If you had the app installed before the obb file could have survived the deinstallation process on earlier Android versions.

I checked Android/obb directory on my phone before installed the app. There was no survived obb file. I'm actually newby with Andorid. More help would be appreciated. Thanks
